# Triggering the save-as website,complete functionality from PHP

Tags: php, html, download, static

I'm using the following code to successfully download a webpage:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.'"'); // needed for save-as dialog popup
print $content;
```

**However, I get a single static page with no images resources**. What I hoped for is the full folder download as you would get if you use the *save as* feature of a browser.

The code above triggers the popup pictured below :
[image]

I have found a number of post suggesting to use `exex(wget url)` but I found that just downloads entire directories in my file structure into itself - duplicating multiple files and causing a lot of confusion. Curl did not yield desired results either.

With both wget and curl, neighter presented the popup window which is essential for a user to rename the download as they see fit.

Comment: There’s a lot to unpack here. Both `curl` and `wget` are command line tools which rarely (if at all) run in “interactive mode”, asking someone to do something before continuing. Are you running those commands on the PHP server or a client? A server can’t natively specify multiple files for download, although you could use some JS and other tricks to try it, but the user could place things anywhere so images would break. You ultimately need to render and combine assets probably into a zip file.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas: The php script is running off the server. The code above does trigger the interactive mode and I hoped there was a way to fine tune